# What is causing the outine on icon?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to set icon for a window like this:

```
var bitmapImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"http://google.com/favicon.ico"));
this.Icon = bitmapImage;
```

However, when the icon renders, it shows a black border around it as shown in the image below:

[image: Black outline over the logo]

Can anybody guide where is this outline coming from and how can I prevent it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange, Never heard about this.

Comment: The border seems to be due to alpha transparency in the icon that is converted to a bitmap that doesn't have alpha transparency. All pixels that are not fully transparent are transformed to full opaque. I'm not sure how to solve it, since I've never had this at hand in .NET, but maybe you can use an [`IconBitmapDecoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.iconbitmapdecoder(v=vs.110).aspxsv)

Comment: @GolezTrol yes. I tried that. IconBitmapDecoder works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried myself, this will render a border around icon:

```
Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/favicon.ico"));
```

and this will not:

```
Icon = new IconBitmapDecoder(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/favicon.ico"), 
                             BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default).Frames[0];
```

So, BitmapImage performs some transformations that lead to an opaque border.